# Snowflake SQL UDF - Unexpected 'create' syntax error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I've created the following dbt macro

```
{% macro product_nums() %}

create function multiply1 (a number, b number)
  returns number
  language sql
  as 'a * b';

{% endmacro %}
```

However, when I try to call it with the query

```
 SELECT 
  {{ target.schema }}.multiply1(5,2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Database Error
  001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
  syntax error line 22 at position 0 unexpected 'create'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The [macros](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros#macros) docs show inline SQL in the macro, not the creation of an actual snowflake SQL Function.

thus for your case you should write:

```
{% macro product_nums(a, b) %}
  ({{a}} * {{b}})
{% endmacro %}
```

and used something like:

```
SELECT {{product_nums(5,2)}}
```

which will generate the SQL

```
SELECT 5 * 2
```

to be run on the Snowflake servers. Aka macro's are processing.